# how to display alert message box with radio button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<html>    
  <body>
    <button id="dialog">Show Popup</button>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var popUpList = $('<div><input type="radio">A<br><input type="radio">B<br><input type="radio">C</div>');
      $("#dialog").click(function() {
        popUpList.dialog();
      });
    </script>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: <html>
<body>
<button id="dialog">Show Popup</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var popUpList = $('<div><input type="radio">A<br><input type="radio">B<br><input type="radio">C</div>');

$("#dialog").click(function () {
    popUpList.dialog();
});
</script>
</html>

Comment: i try this but its cant show the dialog box

Comment: Please edit the question and describe the problem you're having.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/pg8v9090/. Are you loading jQuery and jQuery-UI?

Comment: You need to give your radio buttons the same name so they'll be grouped properly. But that doesn't affect whether the dialog shows up.

Comment: how to load jQuery and jQuery-UI

Comment: With `<script>` tags, just like loading any other external Javascript file.

Comment: The documentation at those web sites show how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you are missing the imports of jQuery and ui

```js
$(function() {
  var popUpList = $('<div><input type="radio">A<br><input type="radio">B<br><input type="radio">C</div>');
  $("#dialog").click(function() {
    popUpList.dialog();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button id="dialog">Show Popup</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture the page load event to instantiate a jQuery UI object.

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var popUpList = $('<div><input type="radio" name="a">A<br><input type="radio" name="a">B<br><input type="radio" name="a">C</div>');
        $("#dialog").click(function () {
            popUpList.dialog();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    //  now we know that jQuery has been loaded and is ready.
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try :

```
 popUpList.dialog("open");
```

Comment: `autoOpen: true` is the default, you don't need to do this.